# Java JPA Hibernate Spring @EntityListeners throws org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, entitylisteners

I am using Spring 3 with Hibernate 3. I would like to update the last modification date automatically when an entity is updated. Below is the sample code:

HibernateConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws Exception {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(new String("hibernate.properties")));
        dataSource.setUrl(properties.getProperty(new String("jdbc.url")));
        dataSource.setUsername(properties.getProperty(new String("jdbc.username")));
        dataSource.setPassword(properties.getProperty(new String("jdbc.password")));
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(properties.getProperty(new String("jdbc.driverClassName")));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws Exception {
        AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(new String("hibernate.properties")));

        // set the Hibernate Properties
        hibernateProperties.setProperty(new String("hibernate.dialect"), properties.getProperty(new String("hibernate.dialect")));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty(new String("hibernate.show_sql"), properties.getProperty(new String("hibernate.show_sql")));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty(new String("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"), properties.getProperty(new String("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto")));
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
        sessionFactory.setAnnotatedClasses(new Class[]{Message.class})
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate() throws Exception {
        HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate();
        hibernateTemplate.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return hibernateTemplate;
    }
}
```

DAOConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class DAOConfig {

    @Autowired
    private HibernateConfig hibernateConfig;

    @Bean
    public MessageDAO messageDAO() throws Exception {
        MessageDAO messageDAO = new MessageHibernateDAO(hibernateConfig.hibernateTemplate());
        return messageDAO;
    }
}
```

Message:

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
@Table
@EntityListeners(value = MessageListener.class)
public class Message implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private int id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastMod;

    public Message() {

    }

    public int getId() {
       return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getLastMod() {
        return lastMod;
    }

    public void setLastMod(Date lastMod) {
        this.lastMod = lastMod;
    }
}
```

MessageListener:

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import javax.persistence.PreUpdate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MessageListener {


    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void setLastMod(Message message) {
        message.setLastMod(new Date());
    }
}
```

When running this the MessageListener is not being invoked. I use a DAO design pattern and when calling dao.update(Message) it throws the following Exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null property references a null or transient value: com.persistence.entities.MessageStatus.lastMod; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: com.persistence.entities.Message.lastMod
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:665)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:683)
at com.persistence.dao.hibernate.GenericHibernateDAO.save(GenericHibernateDAO.java:38)
```

Having looked at a number of websites there seems not to be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to be using an `EntityManager`, rather straightforward Hibernate `SessionFactory`. Another answer, [Hibernate/JPA - Entity listener not being called properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373024/hibernate-jpa-entity-listener-not-being-called-properly), seems to suggest that this will not work without manually setting up the listeners.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have JPA listeners working with Hibernate using SessionFactory and thus being able to use the annotations (`@PostPersist`, `@PostUpdate`, ...),
I had to do the following ugly thing, using the [JPAIntegrator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/ejb/event/JpaIntegrator.html) class.

Here is my Spring bean :

```
@Autowired
private LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean;

@PostConstruct
public void init() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory = (SessionFactoryImplementor) sessionFactoryBean.getObject();
    SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = (SessionFactoryServiceRegistry)sessionFactory.getServiceRegistry();

    Configuration configuration = sessionFactoryBean.getConfiguration();

    new JpaIntegrator().integrate(configuration, sessionFactory, serviceRegistry);
}
```

If it's just to keep a date field updated, you should have a look at the [JPA `@Version` annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Version.html). It's main purpose is to provides Optimistic Locking to manage concurrent update to your data.

Comment: No need for that hack, Matt. Just create the file as described [here](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/EventListenerRegistration). Typically you just need to create it under your `src/main/resources` directory to have it packaged and on the classpath.