# Getting Identity-Generated primary key from JPA

Tags: jpa, insert-id

I'm using Netbeans 8.1, Java EE 7, and MS SQL Server. The application does transactions that contain individual items stored in a separate table. I need the primary key `txId` to create the individual records that are linked with a Foreign Key.
Here is an excerpt from the entity:

```
public class Transactions implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "tx_id")
    private Long txId;
    //remainder left off for brevity
}
```

Here is an excerpt from the client:

```
public void create() {
    persist(PersistAction.CREATE, "blah");
}
```

My major question is how can I get the Primary Key returned back from the `persist()` method?

Comment: flush the EntityManager and the "txId" is then present perhaps ... like the JPA spec says it should be

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34225193/1356423